# WebService Problem Enum Value is not valid

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, enums

Hi I am having a problem with a c# WebService, it was working fine but suddenly it stopped working, I am getting this error:

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Big' is not a valid value for Sources

Sources is an enum, so I went to my wsdl an it was this way:

```
 < s:simpleType name="Sources">

        <s:restriction base="s:string">
          s:enumeration value="Invalid" />
          <s:enumeration value="Any" />
          <s:enumeration value="RM" />
          <s:enumeration value="RV" />
          <s:enumeration value="RD" />
          <s:enumeration value="LV" />
        </s:restriction>
      </s:simpleType>
```

I could see it didn't have the 'Big' value, so I click on the WebService reference and then Update WebReference, then I went to the wsdl again and now I could see the 'Big' value

```
< s:simpleType name="Sources">

        <s:restriction base="s:string">
          <s:enumeration value="Invalid" />
          <s:enumeration value="Any" />
          <s:enumeration value="RM" />
          <s:enumeration value="RV" />
          <s:enumeration value="RD" />
          <s:enumeration value="LV" />
          <s:enumeration value="Big" />       <--------- This one was added
        </s:restriction>
      </s:simpleType>
```

However when I ran it again I got same error.

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Big' is not a valid value for Sources

How could I fix this?
Seems updating webservice reference was not enough. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Albert

--Update

I have added this in order to be able to step into the deserializer

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 configuration>
    system.diagnostics>
        switches>
            add name="XmlSerialization.Compilation" value="4" />
        /switches>
    /system.diagnostics>
/configuration>

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx

This is what I found

global::ReVal.Service.BE.WebService.Sources Read1_Sources(string s) {
            switch (s) {
                case @"Invalid": return global::ReVal.Service.BE.WebService.Sources.@Invalid;
                case @"Any": return global::ReVal.Service.BE.WebService.Sources.@Any;
                case @"RM": return global::ReVal.Service.BE.WebService.Sources.@RM;
                case @"RV": return global::ReVal.Service.BE.WebService.Sources.@RV;
                case @"RD": return global::ReVal.Service.BE.WebService.Sources.@RD;
                case @"LV": return global::ReVal.Service.BE.WebService.Sources.@LV;
                default: throw CreateUnknownConstantException(s, typeof(global::ReVal.Service.BE.WebService.Sources));
            }
        }

Big value is not in the XMLSerializationReader of the webservice.

Comment: You did recompile after the update, right? No offense..

Comment: Yes I did, I recompied whole solution

Comment: Are you referencing the WebService via a Web Reference or by pulling the WSDL and running it through the tool to generate the proxy?

Comment: I am referencing it using the wizard of Visual Studio, "Add Web Reference"

Comment: Is the `Big` enum value in the generated designer class?  Also, is the enumeration being used as an argument to a web method, or is it coming back in the results?

Comment: Yes I can see the Big enum value in the Reference.cs, and it is used in the results from the web service

Comment: Is Reference.cs the generated designer class you meant?

Comment: In your project output directory (probably `bin\debug`), do you see a file ending in `.XmlSerializers.dll`?  If so, try deleting it, then rebuilding/re-running.  You should normally never have to do this, but maybe something in the project state got corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

```
  s:enumeration value="Invalid" />
```

is missing a part:

```
 <s:enumeration value="Invalid" />
```

is that just a typo?
and is the space in

```
< s:simpleType name="Sources">
```

at the "< s" an issue?

Comment: yes that is an intentional typo I have to edit it that way since the page was removing the XML parts